# Can I get the length of the next line after match with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file of sequences, formatted as a line of information followed by the sequence, e.g.:

```
someinformation length=50
JJJIJJJJJJJJJIJGIJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJIJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC
someotherinformation length=50
GEFE?BEDHCBBACEBHAFEBFEBFHFFDDDFD@@@
[...]
```

I want replace the length=50 (could be a different number) with the actual length of the next line (without next line character). So something like this:

```
sed -i "s/length=[0-9]+/length=length_next_line/" infile
```

Is it possible in sed to get the length of the next line?

---

Did a very simple test with time (for i in $(seq 10000); do thing input.txt > /dev/null; done) with a 20 line input.txt file

Suku's answer:

```
real    0m54.932s
user    0m4.678s
sys 0m35.969s
```

Ed Morton's answer:

```
real    0m53.983s
user    0m3.789s
sys 0m33.574s
```

anubhava answer:

```
real    0m55.565s
user    0m5.929s
sys 0m36.049s
```

NeronLeVelu first answer and second answer:

```
real    0m54.688s
user    0m3.812s
sys 0m36.884s

real    0m55.066s
user    0m3.929s
sys 0m36.850s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Anything more interesting is a job for awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/=.*/,"="){info=$0; next} {print info length() ORS $0}' file
someinformation length=50
JJJIJJJJJJJJJIJGIJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJIJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC
someotherinformation length=36
GEFE?BEDHCBBACEBHAFEBFEBFHFFDDDFD@@@
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` cannot get the length of a line. You can use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/length=[0-9]+/ && getline nline > 0{sub(/length=[0-9]+/, "length=" length(nline));
      print $0 ORS nline; next} 1' file
someinformation length=50
JJJIJJJJJJJJJIJGIJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJIJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC
someotherinformation length=36
GEFE?BEDHCBBACEBHAFEBFEBFHFFDDDFD@@@
[...]
```

Comment: You're welcome. In general with awk when you hear any question that comes down to `if the _current_ line contains X I need to do Y with the _next_ line` I find it best to in my head switch the requirement logic to `if the _previous_ line contains X I need to do Y with the _current_ line` and it makes it much easier do write the script more concisely and robustly (and without `getline`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input.txt
someinformation length=50
JJJIJJJJJJJJJIJGIJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJIJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC
someotherinformation length=50
GEFE?BEDHCBBACEBHAFEBFEBFHFFDDDFD@@@

$ awk '{ if(NR%2 == 1) {sub(/=[0-9]+$/,"=",$0); s=$0; next}  print s length($0) ORS $0 }' input.txt
someinformation length=50
JJJIJJJJJJJJJIJGIJJJJJJIJJIJJJJJIJJJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC
someotherinformation length=36
GEFE?BEDHCBBACEBHAFEBFEBFHFFDDDFD@@@
```

- `sub` inside `awk` will alter input string, here i.e `$0`
- `next` inside `awk` will take you to the next line

Answer (score 1):

just for the challenge of time competition :-)

```
awk -F "length=" 'NF > 1 {Head=$1;next}
                  {print Head " length=" length($0) ORS $0}' YourFile
```

with other tuning

```
awk -F "length=" 'NF > 1 {printf "%s length=", $1;next}
                  {print length($0) ORS $0}' YourFile
```